# Multimarkdown tables with pandoc

Tags: markdown, pandoc, multimarkdown

Is it possible to render in pandoc a Multimarkdown [table](https://github.com/fletcher/MultiMarkdown/wiki/MultiMarkdown-Syntax-Guide#tables) with collapsible columns like in the example:

```
|             |          Grouping           ||
First Header  | Second Header | Third Header |
 ------------ | :-----------: | -----------: |
Content       |          *Long Cell*        ||
Content       |   **Cell**    |         Cell |

New section   |     More      |         Data |
And more      |            And more          ||
```

By collapsible, I mean these columns that expand across others, and are represented by the repetition of pipes.

At the pandoc manual it is stated that:

> Pandoc ... can read Markdown, CommonMark, PHP Markdown Extra,
>   GitHub-Flavored Markdown, **MultiMarkdown**,...

But if I run the code above it will not render properly. What am I doing wrong? Am I wrong to suppose this syntax is supported? Or should I activate a flag in order to get Multimarkdown support?

Comment: The mmd syntax is supported and you need to use `-f markdown_mmd` to use it. However, merged cells are just not a notion pandoc's native format understands, so it won't be translated. See the output of:  `pandoc -f markdown_mmd -t native`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Table layouts for use with Pandoc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30528217/table-layouts-for-use-with-pandoc)